# How to Multi-Client in UDP socket communication

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I want to have multiple clients connect, and I want to do recvfrom and sendto.
I have used std:vector as follows, but every time I recvfrom, I put information, so I wrote an if statement, but '==' gets an error.(no operator == matches these operands)

Is there a way not to add it to the vector when the same client 'recvfrom'?

```
std::vector<SOCKADDR_IN> udpClient_list;

addrlength = sizeof(dlg->client_addr);
recv_size = recvfrom(dlg->server_sock, reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&dlg->client_addr, &addrlength);

for (int i = 0; i == udpClient_list.size(); i++)
    {
        if (udpClient_list[i] != &dlg->client_addr) 
        {
            udpClient_list.push_back(dlg->client_addr);
            break;
        }
     }
```

Comment: why is this tagged C?

Comment: does "no operator == matches these operators" have anything to do with adding it to the vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your loop condition is wrong. `i` should be `size_t`, and you need to use `<` instead of `==` when comparing `i` to `udpClient_list.size()`.

Second, you are comparing a `SOCKADDR_IN` instance to a `SOCKADDR_IN*` pointer, which obviously won't work. Get rid of `&`. But even then, you can't compare `SOCKADDR_IN` instances using `operator==` unless you manually define that operator yourself.

Third, you need to add a new entry to the `vector` only if ALL of the existing entries don't match. But you are adding the new entry if ANY entry doesn't match.

Try something more like this:

```
bool operator==(const SOCKADDR_IN &addr1, const SOCKADDR_IN &addr2)
{
    return (addr1.sin_family == AF_INET &&
        addr1.sin_family == addr2.sin_family &&
        addr1.sin_port == addr2.sin_port &&
        addr1.sin_addr.s_addr == addr2.sin_addr.s_addr);
}

std::vector<SOCKADDR_IN> udpClient_list;

...

addrlength = sizeof(dlg->client_addr);
recv_size = recvfrom(dlg->server_sock, reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&dlg->client_addr, &addrlength);
if (recv_size < 0) ... // error handling

bool exists = false;
for (size_t i = 0; i < udpClient_list.size(); ++i)
{
    if (udpClient_list[i] == dlg->client_addr) 
    {
        exists = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!exists)
    udpClient_list.push_back(dlg->client_addr);
```

With that said, consider using [`std::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead, eg:

```
bool operator==(const SOCKADDR_IN &addr1, const SOCKADDR_IN &addr2)
{
    return (addr1.sin_family == AF_INET &&
        addr1.sin_family == addr2.sin_family &&
        addr1.sin_port == addr2.sin_port &&
        addr1.sin_addr.s_addr == addr2.sin_addr.s_addr);
}

std::vector<SOCKADDR_IN> udpClient_list;

...

addrlength = sizeof(dlg->client_addr);
recv_size = recvfrom(dlg->server_sock, reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&dlg->client_addr, &addrlength);
if (recv_size < 0) ... // error handling

if (std::find(udpClient_list.begin(), udpClient_list.end(), dlg->client_addr) == udpClient_list.end())
    udpClient_list.push_back(dlg->client_addr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! When the client close, I coded as below, but C2276 Error came out in ``std::vector<SOCKADDR_IN>::iterator iter = udpClient_list.begin;`` The code is ``std::vector<SOCKADDR_IN>::iterator iter = udpClient_list.begin;
  bool exists = false; //
  for (size_t i = 0; i < udpClient_list.size(); ++i)
  {
   if (isSameAddr(udpClient_list[i], dlg->client_addr))
   {
    udpClient_list.erase(iter);
    break;
   }
   iter++;
  }
  if (exists == false)
   break;``

Comment: @LieuRabbit you are missing `()` on the end of `udpClient_list.begin`. However, you don't need the `iter` variable at all, just use `udpClient_list.erase(UdpClient_list.begin()+i);` instead. Or, get rid of the loop and use `std::find/_if()` instead to get the `iterator` to `erase()`.

Comment: It was a common mistake Sorry.. I have recvfrom inside the while statement, but I don't know where to put it when I leave. I put it outside the while statement on the closetsocket, but I can't debug it.